# Openshift Jenkins - SSL Error with Custom Domain

Tags: ssl, jenkins, openshift

I setup an Openshift Jenkins gear [here](https://ci-xiurobert.rhcloud.com). However, when I use Cloudflare to CNAME it to my custom domain, it returns an SSL certificate error as can be seen [here](http://ci.lightningsf.tk). Further inspection reveals that the SSL certificate is issued to `*.rhcloud.com` and this causes a problem.

According to the [Openshift Help page here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/troubleshooting-faq.html#_how_can_i_disable_https), it says that

> #### How can I disable HTTPS?
>
> By default, all applications are accessible via HTTP and HTTPS. You don’t have to do anything differently unless you want to force HTTPS.

There are similar issues like this in Stackoverflow [(Search Link)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ssl+certificate+error+openshift+custom+domain) but they are for Wordpress.
Does anyone have a solution? Thanks